# Excel only identiy first argument in my formula

Tags: excel-formula

in my list of data, i either have 18 or 180 in cell `A2` and I am trying to get cell `A2` to multiply by `B2`.

My formula is:

`=if(isnumber(search(18, A2)), A2*B2, if(isnumber(search(180, A2)), A2*B2,""))`

However, when i do a find, it will only find 18 and not 180. How do I resolve this?

Kindly assist please.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it works for you. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Given what you want to do in your example I find this easier to read:

```
=IF(OR(18=A2;180=A2);A2*B2;"")
```

You probably wanted to do different things if you found 18 or 180. In that case you have to search for 180 first because the string "180" contains "18":

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(180; A2));-A2*B2; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(18; A2)); A2*B2; ""))
```

This also finds 1802 2180, 218, 182, 0,18 etc.